# Does execution of eval() will only be known (scoped) inside the function where it is called?

Tags: javascript, eval

```
function executer(text){
  var result = eval(text);
}

executer("var _sc_a=5");
executer("_sc_a>6");
```

The second call of executer return me an "undefined" result, is this because of that in the 2nd call, eval doesnt know that `_sc_a=5` is initialized? How should i make the first call known to the 2nd call of executer?

**UPDATE**: The project im working on is a C++ Web-based translator that has the capability to evaluate conditional expr, trace variable values and show the interpreter-reading flow (loop statements)

I have a `next` button that will translate/evaluate/execute fragments step by step as the user click on `next`

```
fragment[0]="var a=0,b;";//already translated from "int a=0,b;"
fragment[1]="a=5;";
fragment[2]="((a>1)&&(a<10));";

$('#next').click(function(e) {
   //setting of ctr here to decide which fragment element should be called
   current(fragment[ctr]);
});

   function current(text){
       try{
           eval(text);
       }

       catch(err){
           alert("Eval error found");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you run direct eval under nonstrict, tldr version is that you are running code equivalent to this:

```
function executer(text) {
    var result;
    var _sc_a = 5;
}
_sc_a > 6;
```

So it's easy to see why the second eval doesn't work like you intend.

---

The issue is complicated, yes, if you call eval directly and in non strict mode, it will introduce variables locally. So you need strict mode to get lexical scoping.

If you did that in strict mode, the variable would not be known anywhere.

If you did that by calling eval indirectly in non-strict mode, it would introduce a global variable.

If you did that by calling eval indirectly in strict mode, it would not again introduce any new variables.

Comment: new info to me, thanks. how would i call it in non-strict mode having that code?

Comment: @fireflieslive The default is non-strict mode. You have to activate strict mode explicitly by `"use strict";` if you want strict mode. Strict mode will disable many WTF-features of the language and make it easier to avoid subtle bugs. More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: Oh, i mean how would i call it so that the first evaluation of eval() will be known to the 2nd evaluation of eval()?

Comment: There is no actual relationships between different eval calls, you should explain the actual problem so that appropriate solution can be used

Comment: @fireflieslive yes, you can't use eval for this.. that doesn't even make sense. You need to get your own hands dirty and make an interpreter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `eval()` is scoped to the `executer()` function and you are initializing outside of that function's context.

Comment: how would i call it so that the first evaluation of eval() will be known to the 2nd evaluation of eval()?

Comment: If you are interpreting line by line, why not join each element in the array up to the current call?

Comment: the interpretation is actually one fragment at a time (every click of next) also, there are times that a fragment element is skipped (e.g. fragment inside a conditional stmt which is false)

Comment: Thats beyond my abilities to hack javascript and to be honest, I've spent my career consciously avoiding `eval()` so I can't offer any further insights into manipulating/maintaining scope and context =\